# Linking error using g++ compiler on Mac OS X mavericks 64bit architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I keep getting this error and I am not sure how to fix the issue....The gcc compiler is 64 bit...the .o files are 64 bit too....any ideas about fixing this?

```
LIBRARIES BUILT ... NOW LINKING OpenSees PROGRAM

make[1]: Nothing to be done for `tcl'.

make[2]: Nothing to be done for `tcl'.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "SMAMaterial::SMAMaterial(int, double, double, double, double, double, double)", referenced from:
      TclModelBuilderUniaxialMaterialCommand(void*, Tcl_Interp*, int, char const**, Domain*) in libOpenSees.a(TclModelBuilderUniaxialMaterialCommand.o)

"SuperelasticSMA::SuperelasticSMA(int, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)", referenced from:
      TclModelBuilderUniaxialMaterialCommand(void*, Tcl_Interp*, int, char const**, Domain*) in libOpenSees.a(TclModelBuilderUniaxialMaterialCommand.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[1]: *** [tcl] Error 1

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

if I look in the TclModelBuilderUniaxialMaterialCommand.o then the errors are:

```
SMA�Warning insufficient arguments
�Want: uniaxialMaterialSMA  tag  E  eps_L  sig_AS_s  sig_AS_f  sig_SA_s  sig_SA_f��������warning invalid uniaxialMaterial SMA tag�warning invalid E
�uniaxialMaterial SMA: �warning invalid eps_L
�warning invalid sig_AS_s
�warning invalid sig_AS_f
�warning invalid sig_SA_s
�warning invalid sig_SA_f
�SuperelasticSMA�������Want: uniaxialMaterial SuperelasticSMA tag? elasticStiffness? positiveYieldStress? positiveUnloadingStress? positiveStrainHardeningRatio?�������                                       { positiveSecondYieldStrain? } {positiveSecondStrainHardeningRatio?}�����WARNING invalid uniaxialMaterial SuperelasticSMA tag����WARNING invalid elasticStiffness
�������uniaxiaMaterial SuperelasticSMA: �������WARNING invalid positiveYieldStress
����WARNING invalid positiveUnloadingStress
��������WARNING invalid positiveStrainHardeningRatio
���WARNING invalid positiveSecondYieldStrain
������WARNING invalid positiveSecondStrainHardeningRatio
�����WARNING invalid negativeYieldStress
����WARNING invalid negativeUnloadingStress
��������WARNING invalid negativeStrainHardeningRatio
���WARNING invalid negativeSecondYieldStrain
������WARNING invalid negativeSecondStrainHardeningRatio
```

I've used these same codes when compiling with Visual Basic on a PC but am doing it again on a Mac and am having these issues.

Thoughts?

Comment: what is it you're building?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's worth noting that GCC and Visual Basic don't use the same build libraries. If you've pulled code that was written for a Windows architecture, you may run into issues. @Patchwork asked the right question - what are you trying to build?